# Server Error in '/' Application in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I cannot open sharepoint central administrative site after configuration due to "Server Error in '/' Application" error. I have located CustomErrors and turn it off in web.config file located in /layout/template

Regards.

Comment: Please elaborate on the config changes that were made prior? Also turn on CustomErrors to get more error information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the customErrors ="Off" in the C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss[yourportnumber]. You can find the web.config file in it.

Also please elaborate the web.config file changes you have made so that we can see and provide you some guidelines according to that.

Comment: I was able to locate wwwroot folder, but I cannot find wss folder in that directory. However, I saw web.config file and there is no 'CustomErrors ="ON" . The content of the file is very short. Nothing like CustomError in it

Comment: @kingruke can you go to your IIS > Expand Sites Node >then select your site and then right click on it and select explore. Try to find web.config in it and then set customErrors="Off"